Should genre tags be included in movie and TV show identification questions or not?
We currently lack a clear policy regarding the use of genre tags (like science-fiction, fantasy, horror, action, thriller, comedy, animation, anime, noir, romance, etc.) in movie and TV show ID questions: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show.
Our current approach is inconsistent—genre tags are sometimes added, sometimes omitted, and occasionally even removed after being added to ID questions. This inconsistency extends to our tag wikis as well. For example, the noir tag wiki explicitly states:

[...] This tag may be used in conjunction with Movie & TV Identification questions.

Yet, even this tag has been removed from an ID question despite this guidance.
In contrast, the science-fiction tag wiki takes an opposite stance:

[...] To be used on questions pertaining to the genre of science-fiction in general, not for questions about individual movies.

This second approach aligns better with Stack Exchange's general tagging philosophy that "tags should describe what the question is about, not just what it contains" (one of the suggested edit rejection reasons). Following this principle, genre tags shouldn't be added merely because someone is trying to identify a show of that genre—the question itself isn't about the genre.
There are practical challenges to consider as well. How would we handle cases where a show crosses multiple genres? Consider a hypothetical sci-fi romantic fantasy horror action thriller comedy noir anime—which genre tags would apply?
To establish consistency in our tagging policy and properly update our tag wikis, should genre tags be included in ID questions or not?

I don't really have any firm opinion. I do agree that we should pick one or the other

I will always go with tag standardisation, but ID genre tags are tricky. The OP themselves can be confused, and what if the accepted answer contradicts the genres given in question later? And then there are movies that cover way too many genres that if they come in ID, how many are we going to put?

I'm curious about the downvote(s). Is the downvoter suggesting we should maintain the status quo? Ergo, continue tagging ID questions with genre tags (or not) at one's discretion?

@AnkitSharma I have the same sentiments. The inconsistent use of genre tags in ID questions only adds to the confusion.

For the sake of consistency, alignment with Stack Exchange's tagging philosophy, and simplifying our tagging process, I propose that we discontinue the use of genre tags in movie and TV show ID questions.
This approach directly follows Stack Exchange's tagging philosophy that "tags should describe what the question is about, not just what it contains." An ID question is fundamentally about identifying a specific work, not about analyzing or discussing its genre characteristics.
Moreover, keeping genre tags exclusive to questions that actually are about genre-specific topics would significantly improve their utility. Users browsing the science-fiction tag, for instance, should find questions and answers about sci-fi tropes, genre conventions, etc.—not a feed dominated by identification requests that happen to feature sci-fi elements.
This policy would also resolve the practical challenge of categorizing works that span multiple genres. When faced with a multi-genre work (say, a sci-fi romantic fantasy horror action thriller comedy noir anime), we'd avoid the complexity of deciding which genre tags deserve inclusion. We'd have a clear, straightforward approach: just use the ID tag.

SciFi.se used to have an ID tagged as sci-fi boat in their chatroom. It could be for the sci-fi tag only; I'm not sure. I am not a fan of genre tags so just sharing it not proposing anything.
